# How do I change WPF Menu's icon column size?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, wpf-controls

I have a WPF ContextMenu that looks like this:

```
<ContextMenu Width="300">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding MainWindowViewModel.NewCommand}">
       <MenuItem.Icon>
           <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/EAV.UI;component/Resources/Icons/MenuNew.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
       </MenuItem.Icon>
       <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

The problem is that the icon overlaps the icon column, like this:
[image: Icon is too big for menu]

How do I increase the width of the Menu's icon column so that the large icon is centered within the column?

Comment: Seems like you need to change your MenuItem's template. I'd recommend editing the template with Blend or looking at Kaxaml's SimpleStyles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a just a workaround but it'll work for every width for a MenuItem's column.
The results will change from this

[image]

To This

[image]

Everything in the Menu is built dynamically except for the Menu's Icon "Column"
Using Snoop we can see that it's actually built up of three Rectangles

[image]

The first Rectangle got a Width of 28
The second Rectangle got a Width of 1 and a Margin of (29, 2, 0, 2)
The third Rectangle got a Width of 1 and a Margin of (30, 2, 0, 2)

I fixed this by adding a Loaded event for the widest Menu Icon like this.

```
<ContextMenu Width="300">  
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding MainWindowViewModel.NewCommand}">  
        <MenuItem.Icon>  
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/EAV.UI;component/Resources/Icons/MenuNew.png"
                   Width="32"
                   Height="32"
                   Loaded="WidestImage_Loaded"/>
       </MenuItem.Icon>  
       <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>  
           <DataTemplate>  
               <TextBlock Text="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>  
           </DataTemplate>  
       </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>  
    </MenuItem>  
</ContextMenu>
```

And then changed the Width and Margin of the three Rectangles like this.

**UPDATE**
The Visual Tree was looking a little bit different for .NET 3.5 as pointed out by unforgiven3, this update will fix that.

```
private void WidestImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    StackPanel parentStackPanel = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<StackPanel>(image);
    Grid grid = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<Grid>(parentStackPanel);
    List<Rectangle> rectangles = VisualTreeHelpers.Get1stLevelVisualChildCollection<Rectangle>(grid);
    // .NET 3.5 fix
    if (rectangles.Count == 0)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<ScrollViewer>(grid);
        grid = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<Grid>(scrollViewer);
        rectangles = VisualTreeHelpers.Get1stLevelVisualChildCollection<Rectangle>(grid);
    }

    double width = Math.Max(28, image.Width + 4);
    // 28
    rectangles[0].Width = width;
    // 28+1 = 29
    rectangles[1].Margin = new Thickness(width+1, 2, 0, 2);
    // 28+2 = 30
    rectangles[2].Margin = new Thickness(width+2, 2, 0, 2);
}
```

And some implementation of the VisualTree Helper methods

```
public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}
public static List<T> Get1stLevelVisualChildCollection<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
{
    List<T> visualCollection = new List<T>();
    Get1stLevelVisualChildCollection(parent as DependencyObject, visualCollection);
    return visualCollection;
}
private static void Get1stLevelVisualChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> visualCollection) where T : Visual
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is T)
        {
            visualCollection.Add(child as T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Visual Tree was looking a little bit different for .NET 3.5. Updated my answer.