# how to change the wpf window's icon size?

Tags: wpf

I would like to change the size of the window's icon in the xaml window.

I know that I can hide the window's title bar and create a custom title bar, but is there 
any way to change the icon size alone ?

I was looking for many forums and couldnt find a proper solution.

[How do I change WPF Menu's icon column size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059626/how-do-i-change-wpf-menus-icon-column-size)

The above link explains for menu's icon size but I want for the window's icon

Comment: For a default window (for WPF and any window in general), I'm pretty sure this is fixed and will always use the 16x16-sized icon that's available.

Comment: so having a custom title bar is the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard window chrome is handled by the Windows.

I guess the reason for that is consistency across applications which is also the reason why I dislike the Office/Ribbon replacement of the standard chrome.

In Windows 8 Metro applications there will be no window chrome so all UI will be up to you.

In Windows 8 desktop applications (and Windows 7 applications) you will need to [replace the entire chrome completely](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/121576-c#-wpf-custom-title-bar-tutorial/).

Comment: Link broken as of 2012-09-06, 8:38PM EST.

Comment: @Urda - thanks for mentioning this. I edited my answer and made it a bit more up to date.

Answer (score 1):

To save yourself some coding time, check out this solution over at CodePlex:

http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/