# What size and format should image for WPF MenuItem Icon be?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What size and format should a WPF MenuItem Icon be to look right?

Right now I have

```
<ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Header="Camera">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
      <Image Source="images/camera.png" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
```

But in the menu, the icon spills over margin, which looks bad.

---

Frustratingly, the docs don't give this information.  [System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.icon.aspx)

Comment: Can you not set height and width within the Image tag there?

Comment: You could set it to whatever your UI layout needs.

Comment: What does my UI layout need?

Comment: I dont believe there is a standard size. You can adjust the column width for the icon and the image sizes themselves. Check this SO answer for some details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059626/how-do-i-change-wpf-menus-icon-column-size

Comment: Thanks ryadavilli, that's how my context menu looks too http://i.stack.imgur.com/IVxDq.png

Comment: You can probably do a trial and error on the height and width to get what you need.

Comment: Using .Net 4 it appears that if you set height and width, anything larger than 16 x 16 gets cropped

Answer (score 3):

I think that the right size of image would be `20px`.

Just specify the `Width` and the `Heigth` of your image:

Use this:

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
  <Image Source="images/camera.png" 
        Width="20"
        Height="20" />
</MenuItem.Icon>
...
```

Comment: Is there any reference which calls out this value as being 20 ?

Comment: Maybe there is... but trying is the one of the best references. :-)

Comment: Very true :) wich is why i had indicated to the OP to do trial and error and check out what fits. I was wondering if it was called out in anywhere in MSDN or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code:

```
<MenuItem>
   <MenuItem.Header>
      <StackPanel>
         <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="PATH to your image" />
       </StackPanel>
   </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

You can also try stretch
[Image.Stretch Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx)